# Как удалять сообщение вызванное нажатием inline - клавиатурой

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Вопрос состоит в том, как удалять сообщение которое появилось после нажатия инлайн - кнопки .
У меня есть список товаров, и после нажатия на кнопку появляется информация о товаре. Как сделать так, чтобы после нажатие на второй товар, информация(сообщение) о первом товаре исчезала.

Пример кода

Хэндлер где появляется клавиатура.

```
@dp.message_handler(text="...")
async def account(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(
        message.from_user.id,
        f"text",
        reply_markup=genmarkup(data),
    )
```

Динамическая генерация кнопок в клавиатуре

```
def genmarkup(data): 

    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.row_width = 2
    for key in data:
        markup_1.add(
            types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                text=f"text {str(key[1])}",
                callback_data="['text', '" + str(key[1]) + "', '" + str(key[1]) + "']",
            ),
        )

    return markup
```

Хэндлер обрабатывающий callback

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith="['text'")
async def callback_1(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    valueFromCallBack = ast.literal_eval(callback.data)[1]

    await bot.send_message(
        callback.from_user.id, f" text {valueFromCallBack} "
    )
    await bot.send_message(callback.from_user.id, "text", reply_markup=dell)
```

Пробовал методы `await bot.delete_message(chat_id=callback.from_user.id, message_id=callback.message.message_id)` и `await bot.edit_message_text()` 
Может я правильно мыслю, но как правильно реализовать не могу понять.

Для наглядного примера цепляю скрин

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы после нажатия на кнопку "text 330708" удалялось сообщение "text 333225" и так по кругу.

**UPD**

Получается менять только сообщение которое отправляется повторно. Как заменять сообщение которое уже было отправлено не могу понять.

```
dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith="['text'")
async def callback_1(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    valueFromCallBack = ast.literal_eval(callback.data)[1]

    await bot.send_message(
        callback.from_user.id, f" text {valueFromCallBack} "
    )
    a =  await bot.send_message(callback.from_user.id, "text", reply_markup=dell)
    await callback.bot.edit_message_text(text='Текст', chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, message_id=a.message_id)
```

Comment: Сохраняйте Id отправленного сообщения и просто его изменяйте на новые данные.
[Как отредактировать сообщение бота](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1276668/Как-отредактировать-сообщение-бота)

Comment: @Amgarak к моему сожалению, ваша подсказка завела меня ещё больше в тупик.
Так как в вашем примере отправка сообщения, в моём же - ответ на колбек.

Comment: @Amgarak обновил вопрос, прошу поправить меня